# Multiple div popups on one page

Tags: jquery, popup

I want to use multiple div popups on one page. I used someone else's jsfiddle to make it work for one popup, but making it work for multiple popups is a whole other story.

I have adjusted the jsfiddle for the singular popup in many ways to achieve the multiple popups, but my javascript knowlegde is still not that good.

What I want is the following: I have six content blocks on a page with each a 'read more' button which will open the popup for that content block resulting in more text in a popup. So each content block has his own 'extra content' hidden in a div. When I click on the button that belongs to one of the six block the extra content will open in a popup. When I click on a button from another block that particular extra content needs to pop up.

I have come this far with my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WGPhG/1122/

And hereby my code (so far):

```
function openPopup('div1') {
   $('#div1').fadeIn(200);
   $('#div2').hide;
}
function openPopup('div2') {
   $('#div2').fadeIn(200);
   $('#div1').hide;
}

function closePopup() {
    $('.popup').fadeOut(300);
}
```

Can someone help me out?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's not how functions and function parameters work --- you can't have two functions with the same name, and you can't put the values of the parameters into the function definition itself. Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) to see the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rewrote your function declarations and fixed some syntax errors, in case you have any question about my solution, feel free to ask.

```
function openPopup(el) {
$('.popup').hide();
$('#' + el).fadeIn(200);   
}

function closePopup() {
$('.popup').fadeOut(300);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JKurcik/WGPhG/1124/

Comment: You can also use closePopup(); instead of $('.popup').hide(); inside openPopup(el) function for a smooth transition effect.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a proper way to call javascript functions. If your markup will remain same all the way then you can do like this:

**Markup**

```
<button onClick="openPopup(this);">open div1</button>  <!-- pass this as a current reference of element -->
```

**jQuery**

```
function openPopup(elem) {  // clicked button element will be referred here
   $(elem).next().fadeIn(200);
   $(elem).next().siblings(".popup").hide();
}
```

**OR without changing markup**

```
function openPopup(ID) {
   $('.popup').hide();
   $("#" + ID).fadeIn(200);
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WGPhG/1123/)

### [**Demo2**](http://jsfiddle.net/WGPhG/1130/)

**Docs**

- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)